# Edittext's width in Android does not matches parent's width

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have a layout that contains an input container. This input container could be replaced programatically by any kind of view.
My input container looks like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/questionLabel">
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to add an edit text, a text area basically in the input container.
I have the following code to replace the input container with the edittext.

```
 val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
 var edittext =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_area, null, true) as EditText
 inputContainer.addView(edittext)
```

Here is my layout for text_area

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/textArea"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="7"
    android:minLines="3"
    android:text=""
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

When I run the app, I see that the text area width does not match the parent.
It looks like this. If you see the line in the image. It needs to be expanded all the way to the right of the parent.
[image]

I want the edittext's width to be matching the parent. Can somebody please give me pointers on what I might be doing wrong? I have tried setting the layout_width to "match_parent" in the input container. But still no luck.

Comment: Because you are passing null as parent instead of a ViewGroup

Comment: I added the viewgroup instead of null and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing null as parent instead of a ViewGroup.

You should pass the viewgroup as the parent.

Answer (score 0):

use `0dp` for width of `EditText`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/textArea"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="7"
    android:minLines="3"
    android:text=""
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_
    toTopOf="parent" />
```

use `match_parent` for width of `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/questionLabel">
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

set parent of editText:

```
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
val parent = findViewById(R.id.inputContainer) as ConstraintLayout
var edittext =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_area, parent, true) as EditText
inputContainer.addView(edittext)
```

Comment: try adding padding="0dp", ndroid:includeFontPadding="false" and
android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"